# Is it possible to have separate permissions for a form and the library it submits to?

Tags: 2010, infopath, permissions, form

We are using SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2010. I would like a form hosted on SharePoint to be available to any logged-in user, however after they submit I would like the library that receives the form to only be viewable by a custom group. Is this possible using only permissions in SharePoint? Or does the form take its permissions from the library hosting it? If I embed in a page viewer does it inherit permissions from the page its embedded in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default view of the forms library to a filter that does not return any documents.  Users can create new items, but will not see any items in the library. Don't allow users to create personal views on the forms library.

Create a document library with web part or wiki pages. Add list view web parts showing all forms in the forms library to such a page. Allow access to that page only for the custom group.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrestling with this a while ago and while I never implemented it, I came up with a couple things to try. These may not be correct (someone else can probably offer more insight) but these are what I'd try.

Create a library that has write permission for all, but not read, then create a form with a specified submit path to that library. I think that should do it. If not, my alternate plan was to create a workflow to grab any form submitted to a "drop box" library and route it as needed. That would be more complex and require more effort, but I think that may be a good plan b. I look forward to hearing if this works as I will very likely be doing something similar in the future!